Problemas con threading en python en Cliente. No se rompe un bucle
Estoy realizando un chat en vivo de arquitecura cliente servidor. Básicamente el programa es similar a discord, permitiendo unirse a salas a escribir mensajes. El problema surge en el momento en que un usuario desea salir de una sala y volver a ingresar a otra. La idea era implementar que cada vez que un usuario ingrese "exit" pueda volver a ver el menú de selección de sala.
El hilo send_message() esta rompiendo su while true cuando se ingresa "exit", pero no esta rompiendo el while true de donde se asignan los threading.
Alguna posible solución? No puedo seguir avanzando
import socket
import threading
import menu, register, login
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

HOST, PORT = "localhost", 5554

def receive_messages(sock):
    while True:
        message = sock.recv(512).decode()
        if not message:
            break
        print(message)
        
def send_messages(sock):
    while True:
        message = input("")
        sock.sendall(message.encode())
        if message == "exit":
            break
        
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    rooms = ['programmers','designers','managers']
    sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    # Mensaje de bienvenida del server
    print(sock.recv(512).decode())
    
    while True:
        menu.show_login_register()
        choice = input("Choose an option:")
        if choice == "1":
            register.register()
            continue
        elif choice == "2":
            username = input("Enter username:")
            password = input("Enter password:")
            login_result = login.login(username,password)
            if login_result == True:
                sock.sendall(username.encode())
                break
            else:
                continue
        elif choice == "3":
            break  
        
        else:
            print("Wrong option")
    
    while True:
        menu.show_menu()
        option = input("Option:")
        if option == "1":
            print("Chat P2P is not available")
        elif option == "2":
            menu.show_rooms()
            room = input("Select rooms: <name_room>:")
            if room.lower() in rooms:
                #Inicializo hilo para recibir mensajes
                sock.sendall(room.encode())
                recieve_msg_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive_messages,args=(sock,))
                send_msg_thread = threading.Thread(target=send_messages,args=(sock,))
                
                send_msg_thread.start()
                recieve_msg_thread.start()
                
                #Esperar que ambos hilos terminen
                recieve_msg_thread.join() 
                send_msg_thread.join()
            
            else:
                print("Please select a correct room")
                continue
        elif option == "3":
            break


No veo ningun "quit" en el código.

elif option == 3: es incorrecto, pues option es un string.

@CandidMoe equivocación mia. Con respecto a tus 2 comentarios, la opcion 3 no estaba testeada por eso no me habia percatado del error. Y en cuanto al "quit" me refería al "exit" para salir de las sala

Ten en cuenta que estas esperando a que terminen los dos hilos (join()), pero solo uno termina, el encargado de recibir los mensajes del servidor sigue en ejecución... Debes detener ambos hilos, romper el ciclo donde creas los threads es trivial, un break al final del if.

@FJSevilla Gracias! Encontré una solución! Me sirvió bastante tu dato, no comprendía la lógica del join().

Adjunto solución basandome en la lógica de join() de threading. Basicamente implemente una lógica donde el servidor avisa al cliente de que salio. Por lo tanto rompo el hilo receive y send.
def receive_messages(sock):
while True:
    message = sock.recv(512).decode()
    if not message:
        break
    if message == "-exit-":
        break
    print(message)
def send_messages(sock):
while True:
    message = input("")
    sock.sendall(message.encode())
    if message == "exit":
        break 
    print(message)

Cambios fuera del hilo:
                send_msg_thread.start()
                recieve_msg_thread.start()
            
                #Esperar que ambos hilos terminen
                recieve_msg_thread.join() 
                send_msg_thread.join()
                print("Hasta la proxima!")
                break

